# FCM token invalidated when app is updated

Tags: android, xamarin, firebase, registration, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am testing FCM within my Xamarin.Forms.Droid app. I have a small problem though:
Whenever I update my app (build a new version and install it to my phone via Xamarin Studio), the registration id is invalid.

When I reinstall the app, I get a new registration id which works perfectly fine. But, once again, when I update my app, the registration id stays the same but FCM does not longer accept it and returns this:

```
    {
  "multicast_id": 7779985059157799056,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "NotRegistered"
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670587/fcm-android-xamarin-notregistered-error-when-sending-message-after-re-debuggin)

Comment: Hi. Do post relevant code snippets.

Comment: registration token will update when you uninstall the app and reinstall again. Check the log to find the new registration token. You can use [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/pushnotificationdemo-fa9c5/notification) to send a push check the if the registration token works.