# Firebase (Xamarin - Android) - Why OnMessageReceived Only Occurs Again After I Delete FirebaseInstanceID?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Why OnMessageReceived Only Occurs Again After I Delete FirebaseinstanceID?**

What I am trying to do is very simple. I want to make it so I constantly get get messages using FirebaseMessagingService.

My current situation is:

- I launch the app for the first time (Or after uninstalling in on the device, or deleting the FirebaseInstance ID)
- It generates a new InstanceID as well as a token.
- I can send messages to the app - and it receives them just fine.

If I stop the app and run it again (without doing things like deleting the FirebaseInstanceID) - I will get the same FirebaseInstanceID (which makes sense) but my OnMessageReceived will no longer receive messages.

After reading all I could possibly find on the web at this point, as well as here - I am not able to answer this specific question - **Why OnMessageReceived Only Occurs Again After I Delete FirebaseinstanceID?**

---

---

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
```

Only fires if I delete the Firebase InstanceID in my main Activity

```
var instanceID = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
instanceID.DeleteInstanceId();
```

**My AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="firebasetesttwo.firebasetesttwo" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  
    <application android:label="firebasetesttwo" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">

    <receiver
      android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
      android:exported="false"
      />
    
    

    <receiver
      android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
      android:exported="true"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
      >

      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
        <category android:name="${applicationId}"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Firebase.Iid;
using System;

namespace firebasetesttwo
{
    [Activity(Label = "firebasetesttwo", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Task.Run(() =>
            {

                var instanceID = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;


            });

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

**My FirebaseIDService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Firebase.Iid;

namespace firebasetesttwo
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
    class MyFirebaseIdService:FirebaseInstanceIdService
    {

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
        }

        public override void OnTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
        {
            base.OnTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        }


        public override bool OnUnbind(Intent intent)
        {
            return base.OnUnbind(intent);
        }

        

        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
            base.OnTokenRefresh();

            // We can log things buyt we are not going to worry about it at this point 
        }
    }
}

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.cs**

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Firebase.Messaging;
using Android.Media;
using Android.Support.V4;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android;
using firebasetesttwo;

namespace firebasetesttwo
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"})]
    class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            base.OnMessageReceived(message);

        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: NOt really familiar with FCM yet, but reading Xamarin's guide on it, it seems you are supposed to register the InstanceID (Registration Token) with the app server? See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/firebase-cloud-messaging/#Registration_with_FCM

Comment: It does get registered fine. I get back the instanceId and the token. Though it registers with Firebase cloud - not the app server. This is a prototype - you later if you choose so can store or do whatever with the tokens and instanceId. The question is why sometimes you do receive a message from Firebase and sometimes you dont? And what have deleting the given instanceId has to do with it and why?

Comment: OK, so I think this is an issue of the registration token being  updated when you uninstall the app and reinstall again, which happens after any code change. See these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686027/fcm-token-invalidated-when-app-is-updated and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670587/fcm-android-xamarin-notregistered-error-when-sending-message-after-re-debuggin